# How to get same functionality as ISNULL in LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, null

I have been trying to find a solution for this since part few hours and I feel like my brain is about to help. I have the below LINQ query.

```
  DropDownListItem item = (
                    from c in context.Practitioners
                    where c.PractitionerID == id
                    select new DropDownListItem
                    {
                        Id = c.PractitionerID,
                        DisplayValue = c.FirstName + " " + c.MiddleName + " " + c.LastName,
                        IsActive = c.IsActive,
                        DisplayOrder = c.PractitionerID,
                        CreatedById = new Guid("COFFEEOO-LOVE-LIFE-LOVE-C0FFEEC0FFEE"),
                        CreatedDate = c.CreatedDate,
                    }).FirstOrDefault() ?? new DropDownListItem();

                response.Data = item;
```

There are instaces when c.MiddleName could be null. How Can I handle it in this query so that if c.MiddleName is null I can just assign a blank "" string to it ? 
Here's what I tried already which did not work out. 
- Created extension to check IsNullOrEmpty. I found out this does not work on LINQ queries. 
- tried converting c.Middle to string by doing something like c.MiddleName.ToString() which did not work for LINQ query either.
Please give me more more direction as to which I should move toward. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for nulls and empty strings instead of using any methods that LINQ to Entities does not understand (`Trim` will be translated to SQL):

```
DisplayValue = c.FirstName + " " + ((c.MiddleName == null || c.MiddleName.Trim() == string.Empty) ? string.Empty : (c.MiddleName + " ")) + c.LastName,
```

Comment: This gives me an exception saying "Unable to cast the type 'System.Boolean' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types."

Comment: Thanks @sarvana. It works perfect after your edit !!

Comment: this works too :  DisplayValue = (c.FirstName?? string.Empty) + " " + (c.MiddleName ?? string.Empty) + " " + (c.LastName?? string.Empty)

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume what you mean by `c.MiddleName` is empty is that `c.MiddleName` is null (because if it's an empty string you question makes no sense :p).

If it is indeed the case try writing `c.MiddleName ?? ""`

This means that if the left part of `??` is null the use the right part of the expression

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx for more documentation

And you would have to change your code in this fashion :

```
 DropDownListItem item = (
                    from c in context.Practitioners
                    where c.PractitionerID == id
                    select new DropDownListItem
                    {
                        Id = c.PractitionerID,
                        DisplayValue = (c.FirstName ?? "") + " " + (c.MiddleName ?? "") + " " + (c.LastName ?? ""),
                        IsActive = c.IsActive,
                        DisplayOrder = c.PractitionerID,
                        CreatedById = new Guid("COFFEEOO-LOVE-LIFE-LOVE-C0FFEEC0FFEE"),
                        CreatedDate = c.CreatedDate,
                    }).FirstOrDefault() ?? new DropDownListItem();

                response.Data = item;
```

To be noted that the `??` operator have one of the lowest priorities in C#. 
Check the operators priority in C# here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx

Comment: I used your suggestion. Now it just returns the LastName. This person that I am looking at has first and last name and no middle name. So I expect display value to be first and last name.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say it now only returns FirstName. No last name even though this person has a last name

Comment: It should be `(c.FirstName ?? "") + " " + (c.MiddleName ?? "") + " " + (c.LastName ?? "")`.  Right now it's the same as `c.FirstName ?? ("" + " " + c.MiddleName ?? ("" + " " + c.LastName ?? ""))`

Comment: If formatting is at all important, this will end up with two spaces between first and last name when there is no middle name.

Comment: @juharr Thanks, mixed up my operator's priority, corrected the suggested code :) and added some documentation to explain why

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused about your question. You are making a string, so even if `c.MiddleName` is null it should be interpreted as an empty string.

You can also try this:

```
     DisplayValue = (c.MiddleName != null) ? 
c.FirstName + " " + c.MiddleName + " " + c.LastName :
c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName,
```

But pretty much all other answers are very similar.

As a note, you are missing brackets behind `select new DropDownListItem`, so that might be problem.

Comment: The query seems to be EF.  That means it's translated to SQL where concatenating a `null` string value will behave different than it does in C#.  Also you don't need the brackets `()` when using object initializers.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 DisplayValue = (c.FirstName?? string.Empty) + " " + (c.MiddleName ?? string.Empty) + " " + (c.LastName?? string.Empty)
```

Comment: This is just returning the first name even though this record has a last name. I would expect First and Last name if the record has it listed.